# Using resolve to wait for RESTful results in angularjs $modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-ui

I'm working on some legacy code that uses angularjs 1.x for a web frontend. I need to create a modal dialog that will make a RESTful call to the backend when the modal is opened and wait for the data to be returned before rendering the view.

I was able to figure out most of what I needed to do, but there is one thing I still can't wrap my head around. My understanding was that I needed to use 'resolve' to define a function that would return a $promise to the controller. When I put a breakpoint inside my controller though, the parameter is an object containing the promise, the resolution status, and finally my actual data.

I can pull the data I need out of this object, but it feels like I shouldn't have to do that. My controller doesn't care about the promise itself; just the data that got returned. Is there some way to structure this so only the data gets sent to the controller or is this just how angular modals are expected to behave?

A sample of my code:

```
$scope.openTerritorySelect = function () {

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: 'prospect/detail/selectTerritoriesModal.tpl.html',
                    controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, availableReps){

                        $scope.reps = availableReps;
                        $scope.ok=function()
                        {
                            $modalInstance.close();
                        };

                        $scope.cancel=function()
                        {
                            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                        };
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        availableReps: function () {
                           return Prospect.getRelatedReps({}, function (data, header) {
                                $scope.busy = false;
                                return data.result;

                            }, function (response) {
                                $scope.busy = false;

                                if (response.status === 404) {
                                    $rootScope.navError = "Could not get reps";
                                    $location.path("/naverror");
                                }

                            }).$promise;

                        }
                    }

                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedReps) {

                }, function () {
                    console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                });
            };
```

The 'Prospect' service class:

```
angular.module('customer.prospect', [ "ngResource" ]).factory('Prospect', [ 'contextRoute', '$resource', function(contextRoute, $resource) {
    return {

        getRelatedReps : function(args, success, fail) {

            return this.payload.getRelatedReps(args, success, fail);
        },

        payload : $resource(contextRoute + '/api/v1/prospects/:id', {

        }, {

            'getRelatedReps' : {
                url : contextRoute + '/api/v1/prospects/territories/reps',
                method : 'GET',
                isArray : false
            }
        })
    };

} ]);
```

Comment: Imagine you achieve your goal -- what you expect to happen if this request takes e.g. 1 second -- what user will see? wont this makes him feel that app laggs? From my point of view it is much better to open modal immediately and show some progress in it, leaving possibility for user to close this modal if he understood that he actually opened it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify things a great deal by making the REST request before you even open the modal. Would you even want to open the modal if the request were to fail?

```
$scope.openTerritorySelect = function () {
  Prospect.getRelatedReps({}, function (data, header) {
    $scope.busy = false;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'prospect/detail/selectTerritoriesModal.tpl.html',
      controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, availableReps){
        $scope.reps = availableReps;
         $scope.ok = function() {
           $modalInstance.close();
         };
         $scope.cancel = function() {
           $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
         };
       },
       resolve: {
         availableReps: function () {
           return data.result;
       }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedReps) {}, 
      function () {
        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });
  }, function (response) {
    $scope.busy = false;

    if (response.status === 404) {
      $rootScope.navError = "Could not get reps";
      $location.path("/naverror");
    }

 });
};
```